# Does Ansible support comment cron job

Tags: cron, ansible

Is there a way to comment a cron using Ansible? 
I tried to use `disable` but it is not working.

Playbook:

```
cron: name="server_agent" disabled=yes
```

Error message:

> You must specify 'job' to install a new cron job or variable

My Ansible version is: ansible 2.3.1.0`

Comment: I figured out how to solve this.  If you want to comment a specified cron, you need to provide "name" and "job" and "disabled=yes". For example, cron: name="server_agent" job="ls -l" disabled=yes   
If you want to uncomment it, you need to change disabled to no. Like this, cron: name="server_agent" job="ls -l" disabled=no
I do not understand why ansbile needs job parameter. I think name parameter is enough as it is unique.

Answer (score 3):

With `ansible 2.6` the following is working:

```
- name: "cron"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - cron:
        name: "test"
        job: "/bin/true"
        minute: "0"
        hour: "9"
        state: present
        disabled: True
```

According to the documentation, this should work since `ansible 2.0`. Important for this to work is, that `disabled: True` only has effect if `state: present` is set. A `crontab -l` lists:

```
#Ansible: test
#0 9 * * * /bin/true
```

Comment: Hi JGK, Thanks for the answer. Actually you do not need to provide minute and hour and state parameter. All you need is to provide name and job and disabled. I have tried on ansible 2.3.1.0